# How to accept a WebSocket extension in Django channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

I am trying to add compression support to my `django-channels` consumer using WebSocket extensions.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        self.send(text_data="Hello world!")
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to inform client that compression extension was accepted.

If a client provides `'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate'` header the server should respond with the same header, however it seems that `django-channels` doesn't have a way to provide it, because `accept()` implementation [is as follows](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/507cb54fcb36df63282dd19653ea743036e7d63c/channels/generic/websocket.py#L48):

```
def accept(self, subprotocol=None):
    """
    Accepts an incoming socket
    """
    super().send({"type": "websocket.accept", "subprotocol": subprotocol})
```

I guess one option is to use [HTTP response start](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/www.html#response-start-send-event) to add headers to the response, but I am not sure if this is the right path.

**Update:** I found out that by [`asgiref` specification](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/www.html#accept-send-event) messages of `websocket.accept` type can have `headers` section. So accepted extensions should be passed in this section.